# "Missing variable name" error when all variables are named

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    const TEST_PASSWORDS = ["fourscore", "Fourscore", "F0ursc0re", "F0ur$sc0re"]

    TEST_PASSWORDS.forEach(function(item) {
        let testText = document.createElement("p");
        let entropy = pass.passwordEntropy(item);
        testText.appendChild(document.createTextNode( // Error on this line
            item + ": " + entropy + " (" +
        pass.convertSecs(pass.estimateSecsToCrack(entropy)) + ")"));
        document.body.appendChild(testText);
    })
}
```

Firefox gives

> SyntaxError: missing variable name" on line 9

(the one that begins "testText.appendChild").

I've triple-checked my variable assignments and my parentheses and not found anything. Changing the `let`s to `var`s also doesn't change anything. Could any of you help me find what's wrong?

Edit: pass is defined at the start of the file.

```
import * as pass from "./passwordStrength.js";
```

passwordStrength.js:

```
export function passwordEntropy(password) {
    ...
```

Though it's probably irrelevant here, I did make sure that convertSecs and estimateSecsToCrack are also exported.

Comment: If `pass` is defined, then this example should give no error. Please make sure `pass` is defined somewhere?

Comment: It is defined. Let me add that information to the post.

Comment: If you comment out the line does the error actually go away? What if you start taking out individual pieces, one by one? So try replacing `pass.convertSecs(...)` with a string literal, etc. And see what exactly causes it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the line giving an error is not that one but:

> let entropy = pass.passwordEntropy(item);

This is happening because the "pass" variable is not defined.